# form validation with FluentValidation and MudBlazor in dialog

Tags: forms, dialog, blazor, fluentvalidation, mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor and i want validation form with fluentvalidation (EditForm) in dialog.

**BookDialog.razor**

```
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        <EditForm Model="@model">
        <FluentValidationValidator />
        <MudTextField Label="@L["Code"]" @bind-Value="model.Code" For="() => model.Code" />
        <MudTextField Label="@L["Title"]" @bind-Value="model.Title" For="() => model.Title" />
        </EditForm>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="MudBlazor.Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public BookInfo model { get; set; }
       [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }
    private void Cancel()
    {
        MudDialog.Cancel();
    }
    private void Submit()
    {
        MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok<BookInfo>(model));
    }
}
```

**Index.razor**

```
@inject IDialogService dialogService

 <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Add" OnClick="CreateBook"></MudIconButton>

@code{
 private async Task CreateBook()
    {
        var parameters = new dialogParameters();
        parameters.Add("model", new BookInfo());
        var dialog = await dialogService.Show<BookDialog>("Create A Book", parameters).Result;

        if (dialog.Data != null)
        {
           //....
        }
   }
}
```

**BookValidator.cs**

```
 public class BookValidator : AbstractValidator<BookInfo>
    {
        public BookValidator()
        {
            CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
            RuleFor(x => x.Code).NotEmpty().WithMessage("*");
            RuleFor(x => x.Title).NotEmpty().WithMessage("*");
        }
    }
```

Error messages show correctly, but closes the dialog and not stop form submiting.

Answer (score 3):

I fount a solution by validate model directly.

```
private void Submit()
    {
        var validator = new BookValidator();
        var result = validator.Validate(model);
        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok<BookInfo>(model));
        }
    }
```